# How to set default role as 'Member' in drupal 7?

Tags: users

If I have a role i.e. Member. How to set 'Member' as a default role for the users after they registered yourself ? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not do this through Rules?

Event: After saving a new User account

Condition:

Action: Add User role > [account] - Member

Comment: May u pls tell me am I add Data Selector as "account"

Comment: It should come as default, since the rule knows you are dealing with a User account, it should create a token for the new user account (are you using the Token module?)

Comment: Yes I just added Token...

Comment: It should come as default then, if you've set it up as I've indicated (as I've just tested) it offers you the new users account as the default token. If not, go to the data selector, and select 'account (registered user)'

Comment: Its not working.. I just create a role i.e. Member, Create a rule & a/c & check through admin that what the role shows in front of that user but it doesn't show Member...

Comment: It sounds like something has been setup incorrectly then, because I've just tried from a blank install using the Rules and Token module, and I was able to do it. Can you add some screenshots, or just upload some images to Imgur or something for me to see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17338/discussion-between-andrew-morris-and-samzha).

Answer (score 3):

Use [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module to set a default role at the time of user registration.

You can also use [registration_role](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role) module to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Smalution.. Is there any other way to solve this without any module installation...

Comment: Yes you can use your custom code using hook_user_insert.

Comment: I know about the custom hook.. Thanks @Smalution.. I think only through these two way, no any other way to solve this.. Am I right..???

Comment: Currently i do not know any other ways if you find any new way please update here.

Comment: Okk @Smalution.. I have one query I am using Profile2 Module. I already enable all the permission of member to authenticate user but in profile2 module, I am not getting any option related Roles

Comment: @samzha it will be better if you add a new question for that so all users can able to see your query and it will be helpful for all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17335/discussion-between-smalution-and-samzha).

Comment: Okk @Smalution.

Comment: Through Rules.. We can create "Member" as default role.. Its very easiest way...

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to use contributed module instead of writing a custom module if it is in stable release and fulfills your requirements. 
[Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) is exact solution of your problem.

1. Install the module.
2. Go to Configuration->People-> Auto Assign roles.
3. Click on Automatic Assignment.
4. Select your default role. (Member in your case)
5. Click on save.

Bingo!

Comment: Thanks..  but what about existing users... If they are assigned as "authenticate" then how can I assign those as "Member" @Xeeshan

Comment: For existing users, you can write a SQL script to update all existing users and assign them "Member" role as well. (User will have both roles member & authenticated Users).

Comment: If you are don't want to write SQL script, you can use View Bulk Operation Module to update existing user roles using user interface.

Answer (score -2):

click edit column on **People** page on specific user who will have role **Member**, and tick **Memeber** checkbox on that edit page.

Comment: Hey.. Please read question properly... I want that when user register urself.. Automatically assign them role as Member.

Comment: sorry, my bad. probably you can implement hook_user_insert on your own custom registration module?